# Recomendation system (vector-vector)

Tags: recommender-system

As I understand classical recomendation system (like Netflix for example) use user-movie relations to predict missing data - rating that user will set to movie.

But what about some kind of recomendation system that operates vector-vector realtions (vector length not necessarily equal), for example something like dating service where each user can be represented by vector and we have user-user relations and need to predict binary score (for example like or dislike).

How this kind of recommendation systems called?